# Ordering django Group model for all related objects

Tags: django, django-models, django-cms

I'm trying to order the group objects alphabetically by name in all usages.
So in every dropdown where the groups are displayed, they should be ordered by name. Right now the are "random" (in the order the were created).

There are some third party models (django-cms: *class AbstractPagePermission* [code](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/develop/cms/models/permissionmodels.py)) which are using the `Group` model from `django.contrib.auth.models`. I can't change their code, so I can't modify the form nor the models...

I can code a GroupAdmin but this is only ordering the objects in the admin itself, not in other forms...

Any ideas?

I guess there is no easy/simpel and beautiful way to solve this.

**P.S. I hate this kind of SO questions myself... forgive me... there is no code to show...**

Help is appreciated!

Comment: You actually *can* alter the models code, through "*monkey patching*". It is however something you should use as "last resort".

Comment: I heard once about patching, but did't remember the buzzword *monkey*. thx

Comment: @zypro "patching" is not quite the same thing - it refers to "applying a (diff) patch to source code". Monkeypatching is about redefining something (from another package) at runtime.